# Are these bounds correct for a double integral in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Problem 26:

[image]

Solution:
[image]

As can be observed from the solution, the bounds are:

$$\theta=0\quad to\quad \theta=\frac{\pi}{4}\\r=0\quad to\quad r=1$$

But from looking at the [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3C=y%3C=1/%28sqrt%282%29%29%20and%200%3C=x%3C=sqrt%281-y%5E2%29), shouldn't the bounds be the below?

$$\theta=0\quad to\quad \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}\\r=0\quad to\quad r=1$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer as @Linear posted is No. See the following plot:

[image]

If you're supposed to do the double integrals as we see in the solution, then the right limits are as you are given (Brown area). While if $\theta|_0^{\pi/2}$ then you should consider both colored regions above which is not intended. If you think $x|_0^{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$ and you want to do it by polar, then I suggest you to add the area of black triangle as you see below to what we had did for brown area:

[image]

Comment: It seems like it is an error in the textbook. The problem says that $x$ runs from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ but the solution contradicts that. Do you know how I would solve this problem if $x$ runs from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ instead of running from $y$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$?

Comment: I am curious. How did you make these graphs?

Comment: By Maple 16 and MsPaint also

Comment: The boundaries for the black region are $\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $r=0$ to $r=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}sin\theta}$, right?

Comment: Nice visuals! +1

Comment: @user1251385: right. my friend

Answer (score 0):

No. Note that the circular arc starts at $y=0$ and ends at $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. If $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ then it would have been a quarter of the circle spanning from $y=0$ to $y=1$.

**EDIT:** Sorry the above paragraph is wrong. What is incorrect is the graph you have drawn in wolfram. Note that $x$ runs from $y$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ not from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$

Comment: Don't you mean the circular arc ends at $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: That will be the $x$ coordinate at the ending point $\left(\theta=\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$.

Comment: And the y coordinate too, right?

Comment: Oh I am sorry, a silly mistake.... :) Yes the y-coordinate too. :)

Comment: Here is what I don't understand. If $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$, then how does it cover the entire area? See http://i.imgur.com/ESS293C.png

Comment: I am so sorry..... there is a blunder you have done when drawing that graph on wolfram. Note that $x$ runs from $y$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ not from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$. Disregard my previous comments. I tried to fix the problem assuming that there is something wrong in what you have done not analyzing the problem fully.

Comment: The correct graph is given here. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3C%3Dy%3C%3D1%2F%28sqrt%282%29%29+and+y%3C%3Dx%3C%3Dsqrt%281-y%5E2%29

Comment: No need to be sorry. It seems like it is an error in the textbook. The problem says that x runs from $0$ to $\sqrt{1-y^2}$ but the solution contradicts that.

Comment: @user1251385: I think the limits in the answer you posted is right.

Comment: Yes. If I took the limits of the question. But as I now see the solution has a different set of limits. :)